# Draw outline round colorbars in sea born / matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, colorbar

After using seaborn heatmap I have several colorbars as axes instances but have no idea as to how to draw a black outline around the resultant colorbars.

I can use `axhline` and `axvline` to turn on the x axis and y axis but how do you draw right and top spines thus completing the box.

I have tried `set_visible`, `set_linewidth`, `set_color` but to no avail.

```
import numpy as np 
from pandas import DataFrame
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


Index= ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee']
Cols = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
df = DataFrame(abs(np.random.randn(5, 4)), index=Index, columns=Cols)


figure = plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
grid_spec = plt.GridSpec(1,4, width_ratios=[5,1,5,1], height_ratios=[1,1], wspace=0.6, hspace=0.3)

heatmap1ax = figure.add_subplot(grid_spec[0])
cbar1ax = figure.add_subplot(grid_spec[1])
heatmap2ax = figure.add_subplot(grid_spec[2])
cbar2ax = figure.add_subplot(grid_spec[3])

sns.set_style("white", {'axes.linewidth': 1, 'grid.color': 'black', 'xtick.major.size': 10, 'ytick.major.size': 0}) 
sns.heatmap(df, cmap='cool', ax=heatmap1ax, cbar_ax=cbar1ax)
sns.heatmap(df[['A']], cmap='cool', ax=heatmap2ax, cbar_ax=cbar2ax)

for axis in ['top','bottom','left','right']:
    heatmap1ax.spines[axis].set_visible(True)
    heatmap1ax.spines[axis].set_color('black')
    heatmap2ax.spines[axis].set_visible(True)
    heatmap2ax.spines[axis].set_color('black')    

plt.show()
```

This produces the following:

[image]

But how do I add similar outlines to the colorbars?

I could just amend the seaborn matrix.py file directly but I hoped there would be a matplotlib route.

Comment: can you add a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the command you are looking for is `set_frame_on`. From [matplotlib's 'axes' API](http://matplotlib.org/1.5.0/api/axes_api.html):

> set_frame_on(b)
>
> Set whether the axes rectangle patch is drawn
>
> ACCEPTS: [ True | False ]

So, adding to your code

```
cbar1ax.set_frame_on(True)
cbar2ax.set_frame_on(True)
```

adds a frame to each of the colorbars in your plot in the way you want (if I understood correctly).

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm afraid my votes don't yet count as this was my first post but this solved this issue. I'd utterly overlooked this method in the matplotlib docs.

Comment: @orgelzyklus Glad to help. If this answer solved your problem, you can still mark it as "accepted" (I _think_ you do not need reputation points for that). More info [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Thanks again, I thought I had.